# Refreshing interface in Windows Phone when reactivating

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

In my first WP7 App, I have all resolved (with MVVM pattern) except for recovering the App from inactivity. I have a main screen with a list of database ítems and a field for each one that, depending on a value and the actual day, shows one value or another (not a calendar, but the same problem).

If the user goes home and, the next day, resumes the App, the calcs must be done again, to refresh the contents. Also, in a second screen happens the same: what it shows depends on the day it is.

How can I detect the activation (I know it is on the `Application_Activated` function, but don't know how to use it) and refresh all that I need (a `refreshInterface` function in my second screen, if the user leave the App there, and the main list in the main screen).

I don't need to save nothing in deactivation, just refresh data on activation only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your page's OnNavigatedTo method you can subscribe to Application.Activated event (don't forget to unsubscribe in OnNavigatedFrom). In the event handler you can then update the viewmodel.

Comment: Sounds very well. I've readed about dormant apps, and I see that the OnNavigatedTo method is called every time the App comes from a reactivation, so one option is to refresh the list in the OnNavigatedTo method. The problem is that this will refresh also when I go from the secondary screen to back. How can I avoid to refresh when coming from back? For your solution, I don't know how to subscribe to the `private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)` event which is in the App.xaml.cs file.